xlim DateTime doesn't show properly with Plots.jl
How do I set xlims on a Plots.jl plot of DateTime value?
plot(df.datetime, pwr, xlims=(df.datetime[1],df.datetime[end]), ticks=:native)

(first(df.datetime), last(df.datetime)) = (DateTime("2024-05-29T04:00:00"), DateTime("2024-06-05T14:57:00"))

But I am getting a view of dates in the year 3993?!

I can't replicate this error - using randomly generated dates/times in that range and the exact same plot command it plots correctly for me. Without seeing the actual DataFrame that's causing the issue it's hard to say, but you can always try forcing it using Date.value() as in here: https://discourse.julialang.org/t/plots-xlims-with-x-axis-given-by-dates/47926. This gives an identical result to your code for me though.

There has to be a bug with it - I had tried that but still got same results.

Can you share df? I can't reproduce it with random dates (works fine) so maybe it's something in the df formatting.
